# How to create a test using LaTeX. I would like the questions on overleaf to say 'marks' and not points

Tags: exam

I am trying to use latex make a test. I am having a hard time recreating this.

[image]

Here is what I have so far- I have got the headings and the box but not sure how to add the name to the right side along with the box on the right that has the total marks.

I also want the questions to say 'marks' and not 'points'. I am not sure to do this either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={fill=white},
          roundcorner=0pt,shadow=false,]{myshadowbox}


\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={},
          roundcorner=0pt,shadow=false,]{highlight}

\begin{document}

{\huge Maths Methods, Units 1/2}

{\Huge Quadratic Functions Test}

\begin{highlight}
{\LARGE SECTION A: }

\noindent No notes allowed.\\
NO calculator.
\end{highlight}

\begin{questions}

\question[2] What is ?

\end{questions}

\newpage

\begin{highlight}
{\huge SECTION B:  TECHNOLOGY ACTIVE}\\
\noindent Notes are allowed. A CAS calculator may be used.
\end{highlight}

\begin{highlight}
\noindent {\LARGE PART I: MULTIPLE CHOICE}\\
\end{highlight}

\newpage

\begin{highlight}
{\LARGE PART II: EXTENDED RESPONSE}\\
\end{highlight}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps a quick look at the documentation would help: "If you give the command `\marksnotpoints`, then the words “point” and “points” will be replaced by the words “mark” and “marks”.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the name, you can use this piece of code:

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={fill=white},
          roundcorner=0pt,shadow=false,]{myshadowbox}


\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={},
          roundcorner=0pt,shadow=false,]{highlight}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{2cm}p{8cm}@{}}
    NAME: & \hrulefill \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{flushright}

{\huge Maths Methods, Units 1/2}

{\Huge Quadratic Functions Test}

\begin{highlight}
{\LARGE SECTION A: }

\noindent No notes allowed.\\
NO calculator.
\end{highlight}

\begin{questions}

\question[2] What is ?

\end{questions}

\newpage

\begin{highlight}
{\huge SECTION B:  TECHNOLOGY ACTIVE}\\
\noindent Notes are allowed. A CAS calculator may be used.
\end{highlight}

\begin{highlight}
\noindent {\LARGE PART I: MULTIPLE CHOICE}\\
\end{highlight}

\newpage

\begin{highlight}
{\LARGE PART II: EXTENDED RESPONSE}\\
\end{highlight}

\end{document}
```

[image: Code example]

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the preamble:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc, shadows}
```

With these packages, we are able to:

### Define commands for the box:

```
\newcommand{\notebox}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
        \node[above left] at (3,0){\fontsize{20}{35} \bfseries\sffamily /#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\onelinenotebox}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[] (0,0) rectangle (3,0.95);
        \node[above left] at (3,0){\fontsize{20}{35} \bfseries\sffamily /#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

The first method involves creating a rectangle that closely resembles a square, which will be demonstrated later as an example for the front page. The second method utilizes a comment to produce a small box beneath the second section.
[image]

In order to make it more closely resemble the reference image, I defined two additional commands to ensure that the titles were of similar length and the second one was displayed in bold. Additionally, I set the fonts to be sans-serif with `\textsf`. Furthermore, I introduced a new environment called `myitemize` to simplify the organization of text within the `highlight` and `myshadowbox` environments. This allows for a more streamlined and less cumbersome approach to organizing content. The code
for this is:

```
\newcommand{\serif}[1]{
    {\spaceskip=1.2em\fontsize{25}{30} \selectfont  \textsf{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\boldserif}[1]{
    {\spaceskip=0.3em\fontsize{25}{30} \selectfont  \textsf{\textbf{#1}}}
}

\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{label={}, leftmargin=*, before=\setstretch{0.5}}
```

### Make the main header:

```
\begin{document}
    % \begin{flushright} - Put everything on the right
    \begin{flushright}
        {\textsc{Name}: \rule{7cm}{1pt}} 
        % \textsc{} - Prints all capital letters, but the one that is capitalized is larger
        % \rule{#Line width}{#Thickness}
    \end{flushright}
    \begin{minipage}{0.695\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \serif{Maths Methods, Units 1/2}

            \boldserif{Quadratic Functions Test}
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.295\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \notebox{40}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{highlight}
        \begin{myitemize}
            \item {\LARGE SECTION A: }
            \item No notes allowed.
            \item NO calculator.
        \end{myitemize}
    \end{highlight}
    
    \begin{questions}
    
        \question[2] What is ?
    
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The output for this is:
[image]

### Make the second header:

```
    \begin{highlight}
        \begin{myitemize}
            \item {\huge SECTION B:  TECHNOLOGY ACTIVE}
            \item \noindent Notes are allowed. A CAS calculator may be used.
        \end{myitemize}
    \end{highlight}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{minipage}{0.695\textwidth}
                \begin{highlight}
                    \begin{myitemize}
                        \item {\LARGE PART I: MULTIPLE CHOICE}
                    \end{myitemize}
                \end{highlight}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.296\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \onelinenotebox{40}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{flushleft}
```

The output for this is:
[image]

I have a few comments to make regarding the code:

- I am not very familiar with the `exam` class, so I had some limitations in formatting certain elements. As a workaround, I used the `minipage` environment along with `flushright` and `flushleft` for convenience. If I were using classes like `book` or `article`, I would use the `titlesec` package to format the elements, but since I was asked to use `exam` class, I didn't want to complicate things.
- I made some minor changes to make it easier to write, such as introducing the write commands and `myitemize` environment. However, they are only complementary and not essential for what you need, so you can simply remove them.
- Lastly, there are various font types and settings available beyond what is presented in the code. I recommend reading and studying the following two links to learn more about them:
- [Font sizes, families, and styles - Overleaf](https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes%2C_families%2C_and_styles)
- [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/)

Comment: Hi! This is perfect. Thank you for this. Is there any way to just add the little box with the marks on the right and keep everything else the same? I am trying to figure it out and it is a little tricky.

Comment: Do you need a little box in every page?

Comment: No, the box is just on the first page next to the heading for section A and also one for section B.

Comment: So for each new section you want a little box on the top right, right?

Comment: Sorry, I just want it next to the sections- yes (not on each page though). Thank you!

Comment: You know how you have changed the font, I did not want to do that. Is there anyway to keep everything same except add the box.

Comment: Sorry, I went to sleep without finishing things, I will resume what I was doing and when I finish I will edit the post with all the details

Comment: I forgot to say, the value inside the box that would be assigned to the test score is a single command which create the box too